# How to style a rect in p5.js

Tags: javascript, css, p5.js

I have a `rect()` in p5.js:

```
rect(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

And I want to style it like so:

```
box-shadow: 20px 20px 50px #00d2c6,
-30px -30px 60px #00ffff;
```

However, I'm unsure as to how to do this. Checking [the documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/style), it seems that I should be able to simply use:

```
let testSquare = rect(10, 10, 10, 10);
testSquare.style('box-shadow: 20px 20px 50px #00d2c6,');
testSquare.style('-30px -30px 60px #00ffff;') ;
```

However, when running this, I'm met with this error:

```
platformer.js:7 
Uncaught TypeError: testSquare.style is not a function
    at draw (platformer.js:7)
    at p5.redraw (p5.js:49679)
    at p5.<anonymous> (p5.js:44342)
    at p5.<anonymous> (p5.js:44236)
    at new p5 (p5.js:44525)
    at _globalInit (p5.js:46308)
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: It's not quite clear from the documentation, but `Rect`s are not `DOM` elements (they're `p5` models that get drawn on the canvas), so they can't be styled using css. You could style a `div` with css though, and `div`s are more or less `DOM` `rect`s.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments, you can't change the style. There are other ways though but they may not give the exact same result.

1. Draw a dark rectangle slightly offset (depending on where the light is)
2. Draw the original rectangle over it at the original position.

Like this (light coming from top-left):

```
fill(100,100,100); //A kind of darkish grey
rect(10 + 5, 10 + 5, 10, 10);  //Slight offset
fill(original colour);
rect(10,10,10,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the "style". [`rect()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rect) just draws a shape on the canvas. This function just changes the color of some pixels, but it doesn't generate any (DOM) object. Think of this function as painting on a bitmap image.